# How can I store particular div id in jQuery var when I scroll that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It should be easy, but I'm having trouble with this issue
I have a variable number of div's with text in them and each with `overflow: scroll`

I want to be able to detect which div the user is scrolling, and store that div's id into a JS variable, but my attempts are not working...

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7pn85ae8/

Comment: What do you mean "when I scroll 2nd div"? Can you post what you've done so far?

Comment: wait i m sending u jsfiddle link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7pn85ae8/ click and check my work please

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it took me a minute, but I see in your JSFiddle, everything you wrote is fine -!

The problem simply appears to be that you are not including jQuery -

Have a look at the fiddle, and then, in your code, add this snippet somewhere before your code:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`

You'll see the only thing that i changed was the alert - and that I added jQuery on the drop-down menu on the left... 
Cheers -!

http://jsfiddle.net/7pn85ae8/1/

Comment: Thanks. it works perfect here. but the major problem those all id's are coming from mysql table. suppose div 1 is for my 1st friend messages, div 2nd for 2nd friend messages etc. so when I scroll any div except div1 means if I scroll div2, div3 first it was not show me alert. when I scroll div1 first and then other then it works ok.

Comment: I really appreciate for your time Sir.

Comment: Hmm. That shouldn't really affect the way the JS works, unless you are loading those posts via AJAX -- perhaps you could try using `.on()` - instead of `scroll()` - maybe like: `.on("scroll", function() //[...]` - I've read that can play more nicely with AJAX loaded elements.

Comment: let me try what u suggest. Then i'll come to you sir.